# Chrome and Firefox giving different results on JavaScript file import of CSS variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, css-variables

Chrome 51 results

[image: Chrome 51 results]

Firefox results

[image: Firefox results]

test.js

```
(function(){
    let template = `
    <style>
        @import url("css/test.css");
        .test1{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: var(--main-bg-color,red);
        }
    </style>
    <div class="test1">test</div>
    <div class="test2">test2</div>
    `;

    class TestWidget extends HTMLElement{
        createdCallback(){
            this.createShadowRoot().innerHTML = template;
        };
    }
    document.registerElement('test-widget',TestWidget);
})();
```

test.css

```
:root{
    --main-bg-color: blue;
}
.test2{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

test.html

```
<test-widget></test-widget>
```

Why are the results not the same in two different browsers?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

`template` variable is not a `<template>` element.

You can create a `<template>` element, set `.innerHTML` of `<template>` element to `template` variable; import `<template>` element `.content` using `.importNode()`, append imported `.content` to `shadowRoot` of `<test-widget>` element

Also, substitute `:host` for `:root` at `css` if expected result is for style to be applied to `shadowRoot` `host`; include closing forward slash  `/` `.test2` element `<div class="test2">test2</div>`, where missing at `js` at Question. Though not entirely certain what actual Question is?

```js
(function(){
    let template = `
    <style>
        /*@import url("css/test.css");*/
        :host {
          --main-bg-color: blue;
        }
        .test2 {
            background-color: green;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            color: #fff;
        } 
        .test {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: var(--main-bg-color,red);
        }
    </style>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test1">test</div>
    <div class="test2">test2</div>
    `;

    class TestWidget extends HTMLElement{
        createdCallback(){
        var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
        var temp = document.createElement("template");
        temp.innerHTML = template;
        var shadowContent = document.importNode(temp.content, true);
        shadow.appendChild(shadowContent);
            
        };
    }
    document.registerElement("test-widget",TestWidget);
})();
```

```html
<test-widget></test-widget>
```

Comment: I can import .test, how to import --main-bg-color?

Comment: _"how to import --main-bg-color?"_ What do you mean?